# call function from span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Hello i have some isues with code below

```js
 <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    jQuery("#check_in").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
                        minDate: 0,
                        showOtherMonths: true,
                        firstDay: 1,
                        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                            jQuery( "#check_out" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                        },
                    });
                    jQuery("#check_out").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy-m-dd",
                        minDate: 0,
                        showOtherMonths: true,
                        firstDay: 1,
                        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                            jQuery( "#check_in" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                        },
                    });
                });
            </script>';
```

```html
<div class="row_field field_text">
  <label class="label_title">'.__('Check Out','tfuse').'</label>
   <input type="text" name="check_out" value="" id="check_out">
    <span class="icon icon-calendar"></span>
  </div>
```

the problem is that I want, when I am clicking on span icon to call the function like it dose from input fields. if someone has any solution please help

Comment: See http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus to input by click on icon. Something like this:

```
$('.icon-calendar').click(function() { $(this).prev().focus(); });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I am not good in Java, can you show me in html tags how to make this possible

Comment: Just append my code to ready handler function. It should work correctly with your markup.

Comment: I have tried many times but I get an error and the page does not display